# Displaying options selected in checkbox tree

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

[image: I want the final output to be like this. So that I can delete or add as many options from check-box tree as I want.]

I have created a drop-down bar, when clicked it populates a check-box tree with sub-branches as well. Now, what I actually want is that, when I select few options displayed in the check-box tree, they should be populated on the top of the drop-down bar at the top, so that I can come to know that,I have selected these many options in the displayed below check-box tree.

Please anyone help me by correcting mistake in my code.

Here is my code,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<style>
    .multiselect {
        width: 300px;
    }
    .selectBox {
        position: relative;
    }
    .selectBox select {
        width: 100%;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
    .overSelect {
        position: absolute;
        left: 0; right: 0; top: 0; bottom: 0;
    }
    #checkboxes {
        display: none;
        border: 1px #dadada solid;
    }
    #checkboxes label {
        display: block;
    }
    #checkboxes label:hover {
        background-color: #1e90ff;
    }
</style>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <form>
    <div class="multiselect">
        <div class="selectBox" onclick="showCheckboxes()">
          <label>Page Permission</label>
            <select>
                <label>Page Permission</label>
            </select>
            <div class="overSelect"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="checkboxes">
            <input type="checkbox" name="Page Action1" value="Page"> Page Action 1<br>
    <ul class="dropdown">

    <input type="checkbox" name="Page Action1" value="Page1"> Page 1<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="Page Action1" value="Page1"> Page 2<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="Page Action1" value="Page1"> Page 3<br>

  </ul>
  <input type="checkbox" name="Page Action2" value="Page"> Page Action 2<br>
    <ul class="dropdown">

    <input type="checkbox" name="Page Action2" value="Page1"> Page 1<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="Page Action2" value="Page1"> Page 2<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="Page Action2" value="Page1"> Page 3<br>

  </ul>
  <input type="checkbox" name="Page Action3" value="Page"> Page Action 3<br>
    <ul class="dropdown">

    <input type="checkbox" name="Page Action3" value="Page1"> Page 1<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="Page Action3" value="Page1"> Page 2<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="Page Action3" value="Page1"> Page 3<br>

  </ul>
  <input type="checkbox" name="Page Action4" value="Page"> Page Action 4<br>
    <ul class="dropdown">

    <input type="checkbox" name="Page Action4" value="Page1"> Page 1<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="Page Action4" value="Page1"> Page 2<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="Page Action4" value="Page1"> Page 3<br>

  </ul>
  <input type="checkbox" name="Page Action5" value="Page"> Page Action 5<br>
    <ul class="dropdown">

    <input type="checkbox" name="Page Action5" value="Page1"> Page 1<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="Page Action5" value="Page1"> Page 2<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="Page Action5" value="Page1"> Page 3<br>

  </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>


        </div> </div> 
</html>
<script>

    var expanded = false;
    function showCheckboxes() {
        var checkboxes = document.getElementById("checkboxes");
        if (!expanded) {
            checkboxes.style.display = "block";
            expanded = true;
        } else {
            checkboxes.style.display = "none";
            expanded = false;
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do check code added below care fully. I have added one more extra div to show selected values having id "checks". Also I have changed values of checkboxes to identify clicked checkbox.

```
<div class="container">
          <form>
            <div id="checks"></div>
            <div class="multiselect">
                <div class="selectBox" onclick="showCheckboxes()">
                  <label>Page Permission</label>
                    <select>
                        <option>Page Permission</option>
                    </select>
                    <div class="overSelect"></div>
                </div>
                <div id="checkboxes">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="Page Action1" value="Page"> Page Action 1<br>
                            <ul class="dropdown">

                            <input type="checkbox" name="Page Action1" value="Page11"> Page 1<br>
                            <input type="checkbox" name="Page Action1" value="Page12"> Page 2<br>
                            <input type="checkbox" name="Page Action1" value="Page13"> Page 3<br>

                            </ul>
                            <input type="checkbox" name="Page Action2" value="Page"> Page Action 2<br>
                            <ul class="dropdown">

                            <input type="checkbox" name="Page Action2" value="Page21"> Page 1<br>
                            <input type="checkbox" name="Page Action2" value="Page22"> Page 2<br>
                            <input type="checkbox" name="Page Action2" value="Page23"> Page 3<br>

                            </ul>
                            <input type="checkbox" name="Page Action3" value="Page"> Page Action 3<br>
                            <ul class="dropdown">

                            <input type="checkbox" name="Page Action3" value="Page31"> Page 1<br>
                            <input type="checkbox" name="Page Action3" value="Page32"> Page 2<br>
                            <input type="checkbox" name="Page Action3" value="Page33"> Page 3<br>

                            </ul>
                            <input type="checkbox" name="Page Action4" value="Page"> Page Action 4<br>
                            <ul class="dropdown">

                            <input type="checkbox" name="Page Action4" value="Page41"> Page 1<br>
                            <input type="checkbox" name="Page Action4" value="Page42"> Page 2<br>
                            <input type="checkbox" name="Page Action4" value="Page43"> Page 3<br>

                            </ul>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="Page Action5" value="Page"> Page Action 5<br>
                        <ul class="dropdown">

                        <input type="checkbox" name="Page Action5" value="Page51"> Page 1<br>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="Page Action5" value="Page52"> Page 2<br>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="Page Action5" value="Page53"> Page 3<br>

                        </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
            </form>
    </div>
```

Following is the jquery code that will show checked checkbox value at top of menubar and also remove it on uncheck of same checkbox.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $(":checkbox").click (function(){           
              //alert($(this).val());             
              if($(this).prop('checked') == true){
                $("#checks").append(" <span id='"+$(this).val()+"'>"+$(this).val()+"</span>");
              }
              else {
                $("#"+$(this).val()).remove();
              }
            });
        });
```

Comment: I have edited my post, by including one image also so that you can come to know, what I actually want. Please try to help in that context. Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 0):

An approach to see on the top all selected items as tags with the possibility to uncheck the corresponding checkbox deleting a tag on the top is using an open source  plugin as a tagmanager.

I suggest you to use the late binding for readibility. So, please, consider to avoid to mix html and javascript every time it is possible. In this way you will have to handle three different sections: css, html and js.

To position the tagmanager after the label as reported in your question I am obliged to chenge your overSelect style adding "z-index: -1;", this means the tagmanager must be on the top and after the label.

In the following the snippet:

```js
$(function () {
  // initialize the tags manager and hide the input field
  $('#selectedItems').tagsManager().hide();

  // handle the selectBox click
  $('.selectBox').on('click', function(e) {
    var srcEle = $(e.target);
    if (srcEle.is('span') && srcEle.parent().hasClass('tm-tag')) {
      return false;
    }
    if (srcEle.is('a') && srcEle.hasClass('tm-tag-remove')) {
      var prevObj = srcEle.prev();
      if (prevObj.is('span')) {
        var txtArr = prevObj.text().split(' - ');
        $('#checkboxes').find(':input[name$="' + txtArr[1] + '"]').filter(function(index, element) {
          return element.nextSibling.textContent.indexOf(txtArr[0]) != -1;
        }).prop('checked', false );
      }
      return false;
    }
    var cachedCheckBoxes = $('#checkboxes');
    if (!cachedCheckBoxes.is(':visible')) {
      cachedCheckBoxes.show();
    } else {
      cachedCheckBoxes.hide();
      var cacheTagsManager = $('#selectedItems');
      cacheTagsManager.tagsManager('empty');
      $(':checkbox:checked').each(function(index, element) {
        cacheTagsManager.tagsManager('pushTag', element.nextSibling.textContent.trim() + ' - ' + element.name.replace(/^Page /, '').trim())
      });
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.multiselect {
  width: 300px;
}
.selectBox {
  position: relative;
}
.selectBox select {
  width: 100%;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.overSelect {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0; right: 0; top: 0; bottom: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}
#checkboxes {
  display: none;
  border: 1px #dadada solid;
}
#checkboxes label {
  display: block;
}
#checkboxes label:hover {
  background-color: #1e90ff;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.bootcss.com/tagmanager/3.0.2/tagmanager.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.bootcss.com/tagmanager/3.0.2/tagmanager.min.js"></script>

<style>
.tm-tag {
  color: #555555;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  border: #bbbbbb 1px solid;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075) inset;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 2px;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 10.0px;
  margin: 0 5px 5px 0;
  padding: 0px 2px;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: border 0.2s linear 0s, box-shadow 0.2s linear 0s;
  -moz-transition: border 0.2s linear 0s, box-shadow 0.2s linear 0s;
  -webkit-transition: border 0.2s linear 0s, box-shadow 0.2s linear 0s;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
</style>

<div class="container">
    <form>
        <div class="multiselect">
            <div class="selectBox">
                <label>Page Level Permission:&nbsp;</label><input id="selectedItems" type="text" name="tags" placeholder="Tags" class="tm-input tm-tag"/>
                <select>
                    <label>Page Level Permission</label>
                </select>
                <div class="overSelect"></div>
            </div>
            <div id="checkboxes">
                <input type="checkbox" name="Page Action1" value="Page"> Page Action 1<br>
                <ul class="dropdown">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="Page Action1" value="Page1"> Page 1<br>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="Page Action1" value="Page1"> Page 2<br>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="Page Action1" value="Page1"> Page 3<br>
                </ul>
                <input type="checkbox" name="Page Action2" value="Page"> Page Action 2<br>
                <ul class="dropdown">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="Page Action2" value="Page1"> Page 1<br>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="Page Action2" value="Page1"> Page 2<br>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="Page Action2" value="Page1"> Page 3<br>
                </ul>
                <input type="checkbox" name="Page Action3" value="Page"> Page Action 3<br>
                <ul class="dropdown">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="Page Action3" value="Page1"> Page 1<br>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="Page Action3" value="Page1"> Page 2<br>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="Page Action3" value="Page1"> Page 3<br>
                </ul>
                <input type="checkbox" name="Page Action4" value="Page"> Page Action 4<br>
                <ul class="dropdown">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="Page Action4" value="Page1"> Page 1<br>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="Page Action4" value="Page1"> Page 2<br>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="Page Action4" value="Page1"> Page 3<br>
                </ul>
                <input type="checkbox" name="Page Action5" value="Page"> Page Action 5<br>
                <ul class="dropdown">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="Page Action5" value="Page1"> Page 1<br>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="Page Action5" value="Page1"> Page 2<br>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="Page Action5" value="Page1"> Page 3<br>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: I have edited my post,  by including one image also so that you can come to know, what I actually want. Please try to help in that context. Thanks in advance. :)